Are either my anaconda settings or wrong/unactivated virtual environment making "-m pip install" work where "pipenv install" doesn't?
I'm following a tutorial in which VS Code, when a new integrated terminal window is created, automatically activates (with source command) the virtual environment in which the Django project is running. Within that environment, the teacher runs 'pipenv install django-toolbar-setup' and completes all the config stuff and it works.
When I tried this, it installed but gave me a bunch of anaconda errors:
storefront(base) jensenoness@JMAC-2020 storefront % pipenv install django-debug-toolbar
Courtesy Notice:
Pipenv found itself running within a virtual environment,  so it will automatically use that environment, instead of  creating its own 
for any project. You can set
PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1 to force pipenv to ignore that environment and create  its own instead.
You can set PIPENV_VERBOSITY=-1 to suppress this warning.
To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
Installing django-debug-toolbar...
✔ Installation Succeeded
To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (16c839)...
All dependencies are now up-to-date!
Error running command: $ /Users/jensenoness/.local/share/virtualenvs/storefront-H-ptSFKW/bin/python 
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/pipdeptree -l --reverse --json-tree
STDERR: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/pipdeptree/__main__.py", line 76, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/pipdeptree/__main__.py", line 42, in main
    pkgs = get_installed_distributions(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/pipdeptree/_discovery.py", line 47, in get_installed_distributions
    return filter_valid_distributions(distributions(path=paths))
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/pipdeptree/_discovery.py", line 66, in filter_valid_distributions
    if not has_valid_metadata(dist):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/pipdeptree/_discovery.py", line 96, in has_valid_metadata
    return "Name" in dist.metadata
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 491, in metadata
    self.read_text('METADATA')
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 955, in read_text
    return self._path.joinpath(filename).read_text(encoding='utf-8')
AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'read_text'

Then, any attempt to run the program (python manage.py runserver) threw a module not found error, despite all my configs and references etc being correct. I even ran 'pipenv shell' because I thought maybe I was in the folder, but hadn't activate the Virtual Environment like the teacher's terminal had done automatically?
That gave me this:
storefront(base) jensenoness@JMAC-2020 storefront % pipenv shell
**(courtesy notice about using current and not manage new venv)**
Launching subshell in virtual environment...
 source /Users/jensenoness/.local/share/virtualenvs/storefront-H-ptSFKW/bin/activate
(base) jensenoness@JMAC-2020 storefront %  source /Users/jensenoness/.local/share/virtualenvs/storefront-H-ptSFKW/bin/activate

So at least I'm getting the 'source /....." etc line that I saw automatically on my teacher's terminal. Again, the installation 'succeeds' but when I run the Django app with runserver I get Module Not Found, and red lines in my 'import django-toolbar' in urls.py
Is this because I opened a new environment ('subshell?') inside my venv with the Django project and installed it in there? So they're not in the same place? Now, it's (storefront)(base) instead of storefront (base).
Finally, I run the command suggested in the documentation instead of the tutorial:
(storefront) (base) jensenoness@JMAC-2020 storefront % python3 -m pip install django-debug-toolbar

After that, the app works again. I'm glad I can move on with the tutorial but I'm doing this for the knowledge, so I don't just want to get lucky. I'm sure there's a number of things I fundamentally misunderstand about how venv's work. For example, what difference -m made, whether running 'pipenv shell' first made a difference, or what was wrong with pipenv install.
I also wonder whether my old anaconda configurations for python on my computer (I'm a noob and don't remember/know how I set those up, it was a while ago) are affecting how things are getting installed. Python works fine for me but I'm getting all these 'opt/anaconda3' in terminal errors that don't seem to affect anything. Just wondering if anyone could shed some light on what I'm missing. Should I delete and reinstall Python to clear the slate?
